# In SpringMVC, i getting a Deploy and Run Project of another System in my Centos 7 STS it gives Error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, ide, spring-tool-suite

I am getting the following Error in my STS Console...

I'm doing all type of R&D. Can any one help solve it?

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
>       [StandardEngine [Catalina].StandardHost [localhost].StandardContext[/neron]]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost
>          [localhost].StandardContext[/neron]]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     ... 6 more
>          Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@32d5223a]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4868)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>           Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@c92f39d]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>     ... 12 more
>       Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
>     ... 13 more
>
> Mar 15, 2018 5:27:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>        SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
>        [StandardEngine   [Catalina].StandardHost      [localhost]]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
>        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Mar 15, 2018 5:27:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
>       org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more
>
> ```
>  Mar 15, 2018 5:27:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>  INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2018"]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)`

This is usually an indication a JAR resource is corrupted. Probably an invalid file in the lib folder of your server. Try going to your Maven repositories and re-download it.

Can you post your pom/web xml file?